# Passing & (ampersand) in AJAX / JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have searched for 2 hours now but haven't found a solution for this.

My goal here is to send a email with a link for order tracking..

Everything works, it's just that the link gets cut where the & char is..

I have tried with differend encodings and decodings but I am stuck with this after some hours..

Therefore I would love for some help from you masters of coding..

Note: There is some parts, mostly bottom, in the pasted code that probably is not needed for the question to be answered but I pasted them anyways just in case they are needed.

My code:

```
var snr = parentTR.find('.comment').val();

var tracklink = 'http://www.silversmurfen.se/?route=common/track&nr=' + snr;
var kommentar = 'Din order är nu skickad. Du har sändningsnummer ' + snr + '. Du kan spåra ditt paket genom följande länk: ' + tracklink;



var namn = parentTR.find('.nameclass').html();
var id = parentTD.attr("id");

if (true == true) { // ÄNDRA FÖRSTA TRUE TILL "knappval" OM DU VILL HA POPUP BEKRÄFTELSE PÅ KNAPPTRYCK.

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $catalog; ?>index.php?route=api/order/history&token=' + token + '&store_id=0&order_id=' + id,

        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'order_status_id=' + 10 + '&notify=' + 1 + '&override=' + 0 + '&append=' + 0 + '&comment=' + kommentar,
        beforeSend: function() {
            parentTD.find('.betald_knapp').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            parentTD.find('.betald_knapp').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                $('#history').before('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                parentTR.find('.nameclass').html("<b>" + namn + "</b>");
                parentTR.find('.statusclass').html("<b>Skickad</b>");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance you guys!

Comment: What gets cut and where? Do you mean `tracklink`? Does it get cut in the client JS code, in the server where you receive it or in the email that's sent?

Comment: tracklink that is part of kommentar, It gets cut in the email that is sent so the & and everything thereafter don't show up..

Comment: I don't see any good reason to downvote this question, please get it out of minus territory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `encodeURIComponent` function will convert special characters in a string to the form data and query string format.

That said, since you are using jQuery, don't generate the string by hand. Pass an object to `data` and let jQuery encode it for you.

```
data: {
    order_status_id: 10,
    notify: 1,
    override: 0,
    append: 0,
    comment: kommentar
},
```

Comment: Thanks.. i changed the data part into an array but now it encodes into:
https://www.silversmurfen.se/?route=common/track&amp%3bnr=aaa
when I need it to be:
https://www.silversmurfen.se/?route=common/track&nr=aaa

Comment: @TryingToLearn — I don't see how it could do that. It should convert the `&` characters in `kommentar` to `%26` and not convert anything to `&amp;`. You must have some other code which does that.